# How to raise notification android app

Tags: android, notifications

I try to develop application which display products item. Can I display notification like Facebook when I inserted new items, so the user only see notification (they know there are new items without open my application)? which event android notification can capture new items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use push notification for it. You can refer latest push notification implementation [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) and old one [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)